# Can't import pygame in PyCharm

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

Whenever I type `import pygame` in PyCharm it says the module isn't installed, but I can import it in the terminal in python mode.

Comment: in your script. you can check if this `lib` or `module` apperas in the `sys.path` list. probably not. and you need to append it.  print the `sys.path` list and check.

Comment: @Adam how do i do that?

Answer (score 3):

In your py script:

```
import sys
##lets check if this module appears in the sys.path

exist = False
for path in sys.path:
    if 'pygame' in path:
        print path
        exist = True
if not exist:
    sys.path.append('... the path to the pygame dir.. where the __init__.py')
```

I recommend do add the path of `pygame` to the `PYTHONPATH` environement variable of the shell you want to execute your script from. rather than editing the `sys.path` in py script directly.

`PYTHONPATH` is an environment variable which you can set to add additional directories where python will look for modules and packages. e.g.:

If you are in `windows` you can use the `set` command to extend `PYTHONPATH`.

in linux:

```
# make python look in the pygameDirPath subdirectory of your home directory for
# modules and packages 
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${HOME}/pygameDirPath
```

Answer (score 2):

This also happens when you don't configure your virtual environment correctly.

Make sure that you select the check box ***Inherit Global Site Packages*** when you are creating the project.

[image: Inherit Global Site Packages]

The main purpose of virtual environments is to manage settings and dependencies of a particular project regardless of other Python projects.